# Error trying to add entries with ldapadd: Server is unwilling to perform (53)

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldif

I'm trying to add entries to an ldap database I compiled, so I have the default configuration from the openldap site. The thing is, I exported an ldif file from an existing ldap server in order to make it easy to create those entries in my local openldap, but I get an error on when running ldapadd.

When I run the ldapadd command:

ldapadd -v -x -D "cn=Manager,dc=my-example,dc=com" -w password -f /entries.ldif

I get the following output:

```
adding new entry "cn=users,o=ctc,c=cl"
ldap_add: Invalid syntax (21)
        additional info: objectclass: value #0 invalid per syntax
```

And this is part of the file I'm trying to add:

```
dn: o=ctc,c=cl
objectclass: domain
objectclass: top
dc: ctc,c=cl
o: ctc

dn: cn=users,o=ctc,c=cl
cn: users
objectclass: container
objectclass: top

dn: cn=AccesoWeb,o=ctc,c=cl
cn: users
cn: AccesoWeb
objectclass: container
objectclass: top

dn: cn=usuarios,cn=AccesoWeb,o=ctc,c=cl
cn: users
cn: usuarios
objectclass: container
objectclass: top
```

My guess is that there is something missing from the main slapd.ldif file, but I'm not sure since I just started learning about this service.

Comment: This is probably because `objectclass: container` doesn't exist, ie. is not defined in any of the default [openldap schemas](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin22/schema.html), in which case you can either remove it from the ldif file, or, if your application needs it, install the schema that defines it and include that schema in your slapd config. "_I exported an ldif file from an existing ldap server_", you will find the required schema in the source server config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by [@EricLavault](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2529954/ericlavault) turned out to be the actual answer. I noticed the difference in the amount of objectClasses in both ldap servers and the objectClass container was missing from the one I was trying to build. Since I didn't have any objectClass named like that in the default openldap schemas I used one named corbaContainer which had the exact same attributes and it worked inmediately.

Thank you very much.